# encrypt the Trigger text

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption, triggers

I do not want anyone to see my trigger query. How to encrypt the Trigger text. Or ask for a password when opening the trigger.
please help me

Comment: Triggers tend to be highly product specific. The [tag:sql] tag covers ANSI standard SQL. Please add a suitable tag for your database product.

Comment: Nobody was helping

Comment: Well, until we know what database system you're using, people are unlikely to be able to help. Triggers are product specific. Encryption options also.

Comment: microsoft sql server

Comment: You asked your question only six hours ago. It was only two hours ago that we established what product you're talking about, and that is key to getting any responses. And, bear in mind that people answering questions here are under *no obligation* to find your question interesting and supply an answer. Don't expect an answer in two hours (I assume, also, that you don't *need* an answer right now). Lots of people are asking questions. You are no more of a priority than anyone else. Exercise some patience.

Comment: Not only that, but a quick Google query for "prevent users from seeing trigger text sql server" provided more than one answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

A quick perusal of the documentation for [`CREATE TRIGGER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) reveals that you can specify `WITH ENCRYPTION`:

> ```
> CREATE [ OR ALTER ] TRIGGER [ schema_name . ]trigger_name
>   ON { table | view }
>   [ WITH <dml_trigger_option> [ ,...n ] ]  
>
> ...  
>
> <dml_trigger_option> ::=  
>     [ ENCRYPTION ]  
>     [ EXECUTE AS Clause ]
> ```

So you can specify this option and your trigger is encrypted. But, hang on a second. Why are you letting things get even to this stage? Most of your users shouldn't have broad `VIEW DEFINITION` permissions in the first place. So rather than reaching for encryption, make sure that your *permissions* are correctly defined.

Most of the people who do have `VIEW DEFINITION` should already be a minimal group and probably have other means of accessing the definitions anyway (by e.g. consulting source control)